# How to add IMEI number to product to check waranty

Tags: magento-1.8

I want to add functionality to check product warranty using IMEI number. if a user ordered more then 1 qty then their IMEI number are also different.

Comment: Is different IEMI functionality is already there ? or you need to Implement it as well

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar : can you share idea how i implement this

Comment: Can you share what have you implemented so far , i mean to ask what functionality you have already created

Answer (score 0):

- Create product attributes **`IMEI`** and **`warranty`**.
- Then create a custom option named **`warranty`** of type **text** or **date** (remember to set it non-required). May be you will need to hide this custom option from product view page.
- Since warranty is implemented on product (not order), so when a user orders more than 1 product, then you can get values of IMEI and warranty of products which are being ordered and calculate warranty till date from purchase date and value of warranty attribute.
- Set calculated warranty value to warranty custom option programatically, so that you can show this value in cart and invoice.

I hope, you could understand the approach. Please let me know if you find any problem.